# find if "qa" or "ua" exists in the url

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Before the release, we want to scan the CMS articles to know if we have any URLS that contain "dev", "qa" or "ua" in it.

I found this regex from  [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

> (https?://(?:www.|(?!www))[^\s.]+.[^\s]{2,}|www.[^\s]+.[^\s]{2,})

I want to update this so that it just matches the URLs which have "dev", "qa" or "ua" in it.

i.e.

```
http://regexrdev.com/foo.html?q=bar
https://dev.mediatemple.net

http://regexrqa.com/foo.html?q=bar
http://qa.mediatemple.net

and 

http://regexrua.com/foo.html?q=bar
https://ua.mediatemple.net
```

should match and not

```
www.demo.com    
http://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
https://mediatemple.net
```

Would be very helpful if you can update the expression here

> http://regexr.com/3dd09

and then share

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to only match URLs that contain those 3 strings.

You can use

```
(?=\S*(?:ua|dev|qa))(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s.]+\.\S{2,}|www\.\S+\.\S{2,})
```

The positive lookahead `(?=\S*(?:ua|dev|qa))` will force the matched string to have either `ua`, `dev` or `qa` in it.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ6rO0/3)

I also replace `[^\s]` with `\S` as these are equivalent.

Comment: He wants to match "http://regexrqa.com/foo.html?q=bar", which has "qa", but not as a whole word

Comment: So, then remove `\b` - just as I wrote - the regexr demo is confusing.

Comment: You expression doesn't match "http://regexrqa.com/foo.html?q=bar" or  "http://regexrdev.com/foo.html?q=bar" or "http://regexrua.com/foo.html?q=bar"

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I have trimmed the answer now.